# I used to be a chain-smoker; now I am abstinent(it was just too hard to get those chains lit)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I used to be a chain-smoker; now I am abstinent(**it was just too hard to get those chains lit**)

What's the meanig of "**it was just too hard to get those chains lit**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a joke.

It is misinterpreting "chain smoker" as "somebody who smokes chains".

If you don't know what "chain smoking" means, see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chain-smoke#English)

Comment: In my youth, I am ashamed to say, I used to smoke Peter Stuyvesant.